# Browser does not expand content when scrolling sideways?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, responsive-design

## Update

Also created a minimal test page here: https://superfly-css.github.io/superfly-css-component-button/target/test/html/test.html

Flexbox is mainly used as the layout mechanism for container elements.  I think i may be a bug in the rendering engine.  I see the same behavior in both Chrome and Safari though.  When in portrait mode on my iphone 6 plus the content initially rendered is clipped on the left hand side.  For example the "W" in when is missing.

## Start of original post

I created [this test page](https://superfly-css.github.io/superfly-css-component-button/target/test/html/) [(source code in repository)](https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-component-button/blob/master/src/test/html/index.html) that shows the subject line behavior.  When I view this page by shrinking it in the chrome developer tooling it looks fine.  However if I open it in chrome on my iphone it looks like this:

[image]

In other words it looks like there's a margin on the html element on the right hand side that is pushing everything over, however I can't see that margin set in the developer tooling ... Thoughts?

Comment: A code snippet would be much better.

Comment: I put a link to the source code in the repository.  The test page compiles to a target folder by running `npm run build`.

Comment: Filed issue with chrome here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=707966

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170583

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
    html {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I added <html style="width: 100%">, but it still renders the same.  It looks like the browser is just chopping off whatever is not initially rendered within the confines of the viewport, so that if I move the page left or right  only white shows.

Comment: what about `<body style="width: 100%">`?

Comment: Tried adding it to the body and a number of other places - the utility is called u-width-100 - still renders the same on my iphone.